# Presentation as iPad Application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, keynote, slideshow

I am thinking of making use of iPad to show customers a dynamic presentation.

Customers will have access to an iPad for it and I won't take part on it, so more than a presentation it will act like an iPad application. (internal links between screens...etc.)

Which would be the best way to do it?

I was thinking of using Keynote but I'm not sure if it would be the best option.
Any other idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend iBooks Author. It's freely available on the Mac App Store.
The interface is pretty straight forward and you can drag/drop almost anything in it.

Check it out here: http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/

Comment: That isn't a bad idea, however, the question was how to give a presentation on an iPad. iBooks Author requires a Mac, and it isn't editable on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Presentation Note. This app is especially good for PowerPoints and PDFs on the  iPad and your customers can easily switch through the slides themselves. The lite version is free, and here's a link:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/presentation-note-lite/id546625319?mt=8